# Java. GdxRuntimeException: #iterator() cannot be used nested

Tags: java, libgdx, arraylist

Как используя эти библиотеки

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;
import java.util.Iterator;
```

Пройти по элементам этого списка вложенным циклом (Соотнести объекты каждый с каждым)

```
Array<MyObject> objects;
```

Пытался сделать

```
While(iteratorA.hasNext())
{
    ...
    While(iteratorB.hasNext()){
        ...
    }
}
```

Но выдаёт ошибку:

> Exception in thread "LWJGL Application"
>   com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: #iterator() cannot be used
>   nested.

Comment: https://github.com/libgdx/ashley/issues/209 похожа на вашу ошибку

Comment: Зачем вы используйте стороннию библиотеку? Почему не ArrayList, LinkedList etc.

Comment: @GVArt потому gdx аналоги работают шустрее чем встроенные джавовские

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё потому-что [Array.iterator()](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Array.html#iterator--) возвращает один и тот же объект каждый раз. И для того, чтобы итерировать по тому же массиву когда вы уже итерируете по нему ( т.е. while in while ) - нужно использовать [ArrayIterator](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Array.ArrayIterator.html) как предлагает документация Array.iterator().

Это сделано для того, чтобы каждый раз при итерации массива вы не создавали новый объект. По этому рекомендую использовать Array.iterator() для внутреннего цикла, а ArrayIterator - для внешнего. Или же хранить итератор и "ресетить" его каждый раз.